# Dynamically Load HTTP Modules, Possibly with Unity?

Tags: iis, dynamic, dependency-injection, httpmodule

Has anyone seen any how-to, documentation, or otherwise about how to load HTTP Modules dynamically for IIS?

Basically what I am trying to do is to load HTTP Modules, which I'll call HTTPModuleA, HTTPModuleB, and HTTPModuleC.  The modules however could be changed out at any time with HTTPModuleD, HTTPModuleE, or HTTPModuleF.  I basically would like to put them in the config file, but don't want to have references or anything.  I'd like to be able to merely have them dropped into a particular path (the dll of the assembly that is), set the config file entry for the file/path, and have Unity, or something other framework just pick them up and load them.  Possibly scanning for changes every 2-3 minutes or something.

Any notions on how to get this done are much appreciated.  Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity is NOT a way to dynamically load modules. You could look at the Microsoft Extensibility Framework to dynamically load modules, which I hear is great.

Personally I built a similar system and used an article on CodeProject for guideance, but I can't find it now. I did find this (which is similar) and shows how to use the file watcher which is nicer than polling every 2 or 3 min:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/dynamicpluginmanager.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can drop assemblies in the /bin directory and have ASP.NET load a module without ever referencing the assemblies in your web application.

Comment: If the module is in foo.dll, then copy foo.dll into the bin directory of the application and add your module to the list of <httpModules> in sidethe web.config file.